# "The program bibtex does not exist"

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I recently bought a new laptop, and have updated it to El Capitan. I have started working on an old paper, which compiled just fine on my last laptop, and cannot get the bibliography to compile.

I am using TexShop. I can compile the main file (in XeLaTeX). but when I try to compile the bibliography I get this error message: "The program bibtex does not exist". The console does not generate any text whatsoever.

I've looked around online but can't find anyone else who seems to have had this exact problem. I'm assuming it's not with my code, as I can compile it on my old machine, but something to do with how TeX Shop has loaded on my new computer?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

the relevant bibliography code: 
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresources{MyFile.bib}

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html as well as all the other [OX S](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx), [mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [mcctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mactex) questions. Have you made sure TeXShop is using the correct paths for all executables?

Comment: Additionally, AFAIK with a recent version `biblatex-apa` you will need to run Biber and not BibTeX since it uses advanced features only available with Biber. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154778/35864, but keep in mind that you probably need to change the `/usr/texbin` to `/Library/TeX/texbin`

Comment: Thanks so much: the combination of these fixed it. I really appreciate your help, Moewe! F

Comment: Maybe you can write up a short self-answer so we can see what helped in the end. Or can you point to one question that we can use as a duplicate?